# Save image in database using file path vb10

Tags: vb.net, image

I am doing a program which save and retrieve image from database.. I was instructed to used varchar as data type of the IMAGE field and we need to use file path for saving and retrieving image.. I am done retrieving the image but i am still working on saving it..

can someone help me in saving the image using the file path..

here is my code in retrieving image:

```
Dim pathpic As String

   pathpic = TextBox5.Text

   PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(pathpic)
   PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
```

Answer (score 0):

There are basically 2 ways to save images.

```
1) Store the Path Location of the image into the database and save the actual picture into a folder.
2) Convert the actual image into binary form and save it into the database. Retrieving the image from the databases requires you to convert binary data back into the image file so it can be viewed.
```

You just can't save the actual image directly into the database. Method 1) is better as it's faster.

This website should get you started for method 2)
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/182113-converting-imagelist-picture-to-binary-data/